HIVE - timestamp difference between CDH and CDP
I have a simple case, where a query returns different results in hive CDH vs hive CDP:
Query: select from_utc_timestamp(to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('1000-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' )),'Europe/Bucharest'),'Europe/Vienna');
Results:
HIVE CDH (1.1.0-cdh5.14.2): 0999-12-31 23:00:00.0
HIVE CDP (3.1.3000.7.1.9.6-3): 0999-12-31 23:20:57
For me is clear that the "issue" is the old dates, because if we replace 1000-01-01 with 2000-01-01, for example, it shows same result for both versions. Most probably this is because on CDP the calendar is calculated based on other principles .
I'd like to understand if there is a solution to show the same result also on CDP.
